# Dictionary with python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def make_scores_dict(names, scores):
    for i in range(len(names)):
        scores_dict[names[i]] = scores[i]

    return scores_dict



names=['Joe', 'Tom', 'Bob', 'Emily', 'Sue']
scores=[10, 23, 13, 18, 12]

dict = make_scores_dict(names, scores)

print #How do I print out a specific name? This is where I'm stuck at
```

Essentially I need to take 2 lists and make a dictionary with keys/values. I'm stuck on how to print out the specified name. For example, if I want to print out Emily and her value how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do

```
def make_scores_dict(names, scores):
    return dict(zip(names, scores))
```

To fix what you were trying to do:

```
def make_scores_dict(names, scores):
    scores_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(names)):
        scores_dict[names[i]] = scores[i]

    return scores_dict
```

OR

```
def make_scores_dict(names, scores):
    scores_dict = {}
    for i, name in enumerate(names):
        scores_dict.update({name: scores[i]})
    return scores_dict
```

Comment: And even as another option, `for name, score in zip(names, scores): scores_dict[name] = score`

Comment: Wait... this doesn't answer the OP's question of how to print out the value of "Emily"?  Why was this accepted as the correct answer when it doesn't answer that?

Answer (score 2):

Once you've made a `dict` mapping names to scores, you can use `[]`:

```
>>> print scores['Emily']
18
```

Note that I've renamed `dict` to `scores` — `dict` is the name of the dictionary type, and it's best to not overwrite it. Once you've changed that, there's a much more concise way to create the dictionary:

```
>>> scores = dict(zip(names, scores))
```

`zip` combines any number of iterables pairwise, e.g.:

```
>>> zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

It just happens that `dict` can take a list of tuples in this format to create a dictionary:

```
>>> dict([('one', 1), ('two', 2)])
{'one': 1, 'two': 2}
```